# Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard + Essentials Setup for Small Office

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, licensing

We want to setup a "small" server for on of our offices (8 Client Computers, local Domain not linked). We need to have an Exchange Server. Unfortunately we cannot use SBS since its support is running out.

We already do have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials Licence and an Exchange Server 2013 Licence (+CALs).

As Exchange does not run on Essentials (thanks Microsoft for that!) we need to run a Standard Licence.

My Setup would be the following:

- Host Machine Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard with Hyper-V on it
- 1 Virtual Machine Running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard + Exchange Server
- 1 Virtual Machine Running Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials (Domain Controller)

As Microsoft does not recommend running the domain controller on the same instance as the Exchange Server and we do have less than 25 Clients i would go for that setup. Seems a bit over complicated but as far as i understand it follows Microsoft's recommendations.

Do you have any recommendations concerning the hardware? Right now we have a Lenovo RD340 equipped with 8GB RAM, 1 SSD 128GB and 3*3TB HD in Raid 5. Maybe we should upgrade it to 16GB RAM, but as the Hyper-V can manage the required memory it could be enough right now. Where should we install the Guest VMs? On the SSD?

Comment: Have you considered doing something as out of your job as professional admin as learning the license conditions by READING them?

Comment: I did read them and they suggest it is possible, but i want to be sure as the fact that microsoft lists "Windows Server 2012 R2" as a requirement for Exchange Server but not noticing that this doesnt apply to the Essentials version did cost us about 400$. For non Microsoft people it is hard to understand stuff which you are not familiar to. There is a reason for such Q&A pages, i will take out the licencing part of my question as this is there is no support for licencing questions as @mfinni suggested

Comment: i dont understand why there exists a licencing tag and i get no warning using it. But i think that is more something for meta

Comment: The SE developers haven't implemented anything like that. It might be nice to have, though...

Comment: You have had multiple questions here; licensing questions, capacity planning questions and some other possibly answerable questions. As it stands, this is also too broad. Consider asking more carefully focused questions about your architecture, but first you should do your own load testing.

Answer (score 2):

> As Microsoft does not recommend running the domain controller on the same instance as the Exchange Server

In a situation this small I'd disregard that recommendation. If you're planning on substantial growth in the next 2-3 years you should consider doing the VM setup you proposed. Also, at this size I'd strongly consider a hosted solution for Exchange, unless you bought the licenses already.

> Do you have any recommendations concerning the hardware?

Make sure you have backups - and not on that 3x3TB SATA array (see this for why: [What counts as a 'large' raid 5 array?](https://serverfault.com/questions/591777/what-counts-as-a-large-raid-5-array) )

> Where should we install the Guest VMs? On the SSD?

I really can't recommend getting a descent consultant to look at your situation enough. It sounds like you've already made some mistakes that cost hundreds in licensing, the last thing you need is for that to be a regular occurrence. It's apparent you aren't familiar with System Administration work.

Comment: thank you for your advice. We will have a backup solution to another location, so this should be fine. You are right, we are no System Admins but we are an engineering company with enough basics to get this up and running. A hosted solution would be a better fit but the local server is a requirement. We are going to learn a lot during the setup and i want to mention here that we are going to use that solution by ourselves not selling it to anyone. I've got the feeling that there is a misunderstanding.